# Run a local script with configuration file remotely over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, configuration, scripting, scp

I am trying to run a script that takes a configuration file over on a remote server. 
Currently I scp the file over to remote server then run the local script over on the server.

`script=localscript.sh
conf=script.conf
ssh USER@REMOTE_HOST "bash -s" < "$script $conf"`

I get the following error:
`localscript.sh script.conf: No such file or directory`

I tried to google and use other resources but was unable to locate anything like my example.
Is there any tool or option that can assist me with this.

Answer (score 0):

"No such file or directory" is telling you clearly that the file is not there. So either your scp failed or the you need the full path of the file location. Add a check for the file and also check if the scp was successful or not.

Comment: Yea, I get that, but i am trying to avoid scping in the first place.  Currently, if the scp were to fail on 10/100 nodes then i cannot run my local script on 10 of those nodes.  Try to read the comment above. i tired my best to explain whats going on.  The currently implementation for this already has all of those checks in place. i am trying to combine an avoid making two separate connection to a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that error message is from localscript.sh, i.e. that that is successfully running but that it can't find the config file. Is script.conf in the home directory of USER?

Comment: Short answer no, Long answer when i run the localscript.sh by it self, it is ran on the remote server.  But when i try to pass the localconfig file, i get the above error. From my understanding, i believe the remote server is trying to look for the localconfig on its own file structure.  But realistically, the localscript and script.conf are both located on my local machine.

Comment: Ah; try `ssh USER@REMOTE_HOST "bash $script" < $conf`

Comment: The issue with that is that it's looking for that script on remote sever and not my local machine.

Comment: Right, sorry, I understand now. Unfortunately if you send the script by stdin, you can't then pipe anything into it. I think the easiest thing to do is to copy one of the files to the server, unless you can edit the script so that the configuration data is built in

Comment: Thanks for that information, I thought about doing that but it required a whole lot of script editing.  But i spoke to an senior architect and he suggested we should ditch the bash and try working with ruby instead.  So will be heading in that direction.  But this was informational so thanks once again.